# Is $\frac{21}2+\sum_{n=0}^{18}\frac{n+2}{n+3}$ greater than $21?24?27?30?$

Tags: sequences-and-series

The following summation is $>$ which of the following integers$?$
$$\frac{21}2+\sum_{n=0}^{18}\frac{n+2}{n+3}$$
There are four options

($a$) 21

($b$) 24

($c$) 27

($d$) 30.

First of all I am trying this question by assuming the above series to be $S$ and by applying the A.M.$-$G.M. inequality. So, the series is $S$=(2$/$3)$+$(3$/$4)$+$(4$/$5)$+$...$+$(20$/$21)$+$(21$/$2). Now, after applying A.M.$-$G.M. inequality I am getting the above summation to be greater than 21. But still I am confused whether my method of solving is correct or not. Because the following summation can also be$>$24 and $<$27 or$>$27 and $<$30. In both the cases $i.e.$(in the 1st case 24$<$$S$$<$27 and in the 2nd case 27$<$$S$$<$30); S is always $>$21.

Comment: Please [(type and) format your formulas](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: The sum contains not so much terms, so it can be calculated by phone calculator.
$\frac{n+2}{n+3}=1-\frac{1}{n+3}$. $1/3+1/4+...+1/21$ can be estimated as $\ln(21.5/2.5)$

Comment: How to calculate the sum without using calculator?@IvanKaznacheyeu

Answer (score 3):

$$\begin{align}\frac{21}2+\sum_{n=0}^{18}\frac{n+2}{n+3}&=\frac{21}2+\sum_{k=3}^{21}\frac{k-1}k\\
&=\frac{21}2+19-\sum_{k=3}^{21}\frac1k\\
&=31-H_{21}\\
&\approx27.4,
\end{align}$$
since [$H_{21}\approx\ln(21)+\gamma$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Calculation) $\approx3.6.$

Comment: But the Euler's formula $i.e.$ $$\sum_{i=1}^{n} 1/i$$=$ln$($n$)$+$$\gamma$ is applicable only when n is a large no.. For $e.g.$$-$ $n$ can be considered $\ge$100.

Comment: Here for this question n=21. Can this formula be applicable here?

Comment: The error is $<\frac1{2n}.$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)#Growth_rate